# colcon build exclude package

Tags: ros2, colcon

Can it be possible to exclude a package from build process, my modifying its CMakeLists.txt

So the catkin build command will skip that directory?

Best Regards,
C.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to use **colcon** *(mentioned in title)*, or **catkin** *(mentioned in body)*?

In case it's colcon, creating an empty file called `COLCON_IGNORE` in the root of the package you want to exclude will do that. In case you do not want to create the `COLCON_IGNORE` file, you may also use the option `colcon build --packages-ignore <name-of-package>` to let colcon know to ignore a particular package while building.

In case it's catkin, IIRC, the idea remains the same. You have to create a file called `CATKIN_IGNORE` and that should do it.